# How to get a byte [ ] from an OutputStream to retrieve uploaded file

Tags: java, vaadin

After receiving the uploaded file i want to return a byte[ ] representing the uploaded file i overrode the receiveUpload methode:

```
/**
     * Invoked when a new upload arrives.
     * 
     * @param filename
     *            the desired filename of the upload, usually as specified
     *            by the client.
     * @param mimeType
     *            the MIME type of the uploaded file.
     * @return Stream to which the uploaded file should be written.
     */
    public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename, String mimeType);
```

But it returns an OutputStream 
Here's the full implementation :

```
class FileUploaderReceiver implements Receiver{
    public File file;

    @Override
    public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename,
                                      String mimeType) {
        // Create upload stream
      OutputStream fos = null; // Stream to write to
        try {
            // Open the file for writing.
            file = new File("/tmp/uploads/" + filename);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

        } catch (final java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
            new Notification("Could not open file<br/>",
                             e.getMessage(),
                             Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE)
                .show(Page.getCurrent());
            return null;
        }
        return fos; // Return the output stream to write to
    }
```

So how to get the byte[ ], i know that i can retrieve it using the  ByteArrayOutputStream class, but i'am blocked.

Any idea will be appreciated,

Thank you

Comment: I think you need `InputStream`, not output, you're trying to read the file not write to it.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `OutputStream`  with a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then use [toByteArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

As kostyan mentioned, you need to use an InputStream (with respect to your method intention). From the InputStream, you can get the bytes, using something like this: http://lasanthals.blogspot.de/2012/09/get-byte-array-from-inputstream.html.

Do note, I provide this as a quick answer, from a quick search, have not tried this one myself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how to be notified when the data is fully written to the returned stream.

You can return a `ByteArrayOutputStream` with overriden `close()` method. When the stream gets closed, you'll know that the upload was fully written to that stream.

```
public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename, String mimeType) {
    return new ByteArrayOutputStream() {
        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            byte[] uploadData = toByteArray();
            //....
        }
    };
}
```